# when i scroll down will cause multiple ajax request and data shows randomly(different page index not sequencely)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I do scroll down the page to a certain point (60%), will call c# web method from code file, but when i scroll down will cause multiple ajax request and data shows randomly(different page index not sequencely)

```
<script>
var pageIndex = 1;
var pageCount;
$(document).ready(function () {
var cnt = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())* 0.6) {
   cnt++;
    pageIndex++;
    if (cnt <= 10) {
       document.getElementById('footer').style.display = 'none';
       WhatsHotData();
    }
    else {
          document.getElementById('footer').style.display = 'block';
         }
       }
    });

   function WhatsHotData() {
    $("#loader").show();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "index.aspx/GetWhatHotData",
      data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      async: "true",
      cache: "false",

    success: function (msg) {
    $("#loader").hide();
    $("#divWhatsHot ul").append(msg.d);
    },
    Error: function (x, e) {
     console.log("Some error");
     }
   });
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the call to happen once, you need to add a flag that prevents it from being called a second time (or put in some kind of throttling, if you still want it to happen more than once).

What happens right now is that the code is called for every pixel you scroll, because $(window).scroll is called repeatedly while you're scrolling.